# Formatting a Double into the correct format

Tags: java

Having problem getting a Longitude/Latitude into the correct format for an api we don't have access to.

We need to convert this to a string and at the moment we have:   4.30044549E7
as the raw form but we need to convert it into 4.30044549 or similar (without Scientific Notation)

If we use

```
NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#.#######");
f.format(4.30044549E7);
```

we get: 43004454.9

if we use

```
Double.toString(4.30044549E7);
```

we get: "4.30044549E7"

if we try to convert to an int we also get 43004454.9

Can anyone help? I can't find an acceptable solution to get rid of scientific notation on the number

Comment: 4.30044549e7 isn't a latitude or longitude (at least, not in degrees)... it sounds like maybe you have other issues.

Comment: could you please elaborate on how input numbers in general (not just 4.30044549e7) should be converted? For example, what should 6.123e6 and 9.3145e5 be converted to?

Comment: The e is produced when a number is too long for a double, so the value is a correct for either a latitude or a longitude but is simply far too precise for a Double to handle and thus it's "rounded" using E

Comment: Those aren't lat/lon, but probably some set of metric geographical coordinates, e.g. UTM.

Answer (score 3):

If you really asked what I think you did, you could simply divide the number by 10 until you reach the format you wanted.

```
double value = 4.30044549E7;
while(value > 10 || value < -10){
  value /= 10;
}

System.out.println(String.format("%.8f", value)); //4.30044549
```

Comment: what happens if value = -3.12e7?

Comment: @Jason S `while (value > 10 || value < -10) { ...`

Comment: ...or value = 10.0? should the result be 10.0 or 1.0?

Comment: I figured latitude and longitude would be given in N/S/E/W terms, but yeah I guess since the numbers don't seem to make sense it could be something that happens. :P Edited.

Comment: @Vache +1 (random words to exceed minimum character limit)

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Yes, question is not entirely clear for me.

Comment: I just want to produce a valid number based on the original number but without the E... if that means we're rounding down to x decimal places that's fine but it needs to be accurate

Comment: ...and what about value = 0.013456? or value = 0?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `format`?

```
String.format("%.10f",doubleValue);
```

It will format your number with 10 digits after dot.

```
1e-5 -> 0.000010000
1e5  -> 100000.0000000000
```

Comment: He wants to drop the E# without moving the `.`. So 1E5 -> 1

Comment: @Vache -- how do you know that? I think the OP has not fully specified the problem.

Comment: @Vache, if they use it to pass coordinates to api, then it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Jason: Well that's what I understood from the 2nd line of the question... Nikita: Maybe, but say that to OP :P

Comment: @Vache: OP said he wants 4.30044549e7 converted to "4.30044549 or similar". I don't know what "or similar" means, and I don't know whether 4.30044549e6 should be converted to 4.30044549 or 0.430044549. If the problem is "find the mantissa", then it's the former, but that makes little sense in a numeric conversion application. Otherwise the problem is scale by 10^-7, but in that case it should be stated as part of the problem statement.

Comment: Basically we want the correct number in string format without the E overflow for double - I can simply parse the resulting string but I didn't know if there was a more elegent way of doing it. 

The API we're working with see's the E as an invalid number (and we don't have access to modify the API even though it should be doing it correctly) So we have to create a solution which sends a valid latitude / longitude without the E constant.

Answer (score 1):

you never can "format" 4.30044549E7 into 4.30044549 because they are not the same.

4.30044549E7 is in fact 43004454.9 so wanting a formatter to display that double as 4.30044549 is an odd question

Comment: +1 for accuracy -- can't really answer the question until the OP specifies.